# Python Dataframe apply a function across expanding/running range with a groupby

Tags: python

Using the quantopian max_drawdown function I'm trying to calculate max_drawdown over an expanding data range - so I'm expecting multiple different outputs.

```
from empyrical import max_drawdown
import pandas as pd

returns = pd.DataFrame({
        'value_date' : ['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31','2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', 
                        '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31','2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30'],
        'code_id' :  ['AUD','AUD','AUD','AUD','AUD','AUD', 
                      'USD','USD','USD','USD','USD','USD'],
        'gross_return': [.01, .02, .03, -.4, -.06, -.02, 
                         .06, .8, .9, .4, -1.06, .03],
        })
```

This bit of code is very close - but it isn't expanding/running, rather it is just using the whole range dataframe (grouped by code_id).

```
returns['max_drawdown'] = returns.groupby(['code_id'])['gross_return'].transform(lambda x: max_drawdown(x))
```

I tried the following

```
returns['max_drawdown'] = returns.groupby(['code_id'])['gross_return'].expanding().transform(lambda x: max_drawdown(x))
```

But get `AttributeError: 'ExpandingGroupby' object has no attribute 'transform'

Any ideas please

**Function Library**

https://github.com/quantopian/empyrical/blob/master/empyrical/stats.py

**UPDATE**

This works

```
print(returns.groupby(['code_id'])['gross_return'].expanding().apply(lambda x: max_drawdown(x)))
```

however this does not `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

```
returns['max_drawdown'] = returns.groupby(['code_id'])['gross_return'].expanding().apply(lambda x: max_drawdown(x))
```